# Rails: Bootstrap glyphicons not loading in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-sass

After upgrading to Rails 5, the Bootstrap glyphicon icons are not loading properly on heroku. For instance, the Trashcan icon is showing up as a question mark. It appears that the browser is not finding the glyphicon asset and loading its own interpretation.  I am using `bootstrap-sass 3.3.7`.

When the glyphicons are loaded, if I open the console, I see errors like this:

```
A server with the specified hostname could not be found
https://assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-fe185d11a49676890d47bb783312a0cda5a44c4039214094e7957b4c040ef11c.woff2
```

It looks to me that the asset host is not being set properly for the bootstrap assets.
In my `production.rb` file, I have the line

```
config.asset_host = "https://#{ENV['RAILS_HOST_PATH']}"
```

and if I do `heroku config --remote production`, the value of `RAILS_HOST_PATH` is `www.example.com`.

If I look at `Rails.application.config.asset_host` it does correctly show 
`"https://www.example.com"`.  However it looks like for the bootstrap assets, the domain is resolved as `https://`.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further investigation revealed that it was not a problem with Rails 5 per se, but due to changing the `production.rb` file in upgrade, and following [Heroku's advice](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-to-a-custom-rails-environment) on using ENV variables for such files.

Accordingly, I needed to specify the target RAILS_HOST_PATH in the precompilation i.e.
`RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_HOST_PATH=www.example.com rake assets:precompile`